# Trying to create a 3D matrix in Python by choosing specific data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi so I'm trying to make a 3D matrix here.. It's the MovieLens data (https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/)  from where I'm taking a `u1.base` and `u1.test` pair as training and test sets (respectively). Below is an image of the format of the data of variable `training_set` you'll discover in the code.

[image]

The 3D matrix I'm trying to create is of the format `(User, Movie, Timestamp)` and the data in each of those cells is the ratings given by, for example, user 1 to movie 1 at time 1.

If it's any help, below is the code where a 2D matrix is created with **users in the rows and all the movies as the columns.**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

training_set = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u1.base', delimiter = '\t')
training_set = np.array(training_set, dtype='int')
test_set = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u1.test', delimiter = '\t')
test_set = np.array(test_set, dtype = 'int64')

nb_users = int(max(max(training_set[:, 0]), max(test_set[:, 0])))
nb_movies = int(max(max(training_set[:, 1]), max(test_set[:, 1]))) 

def convert(data):
    new_data = [] #final list that we will return
    for id_users in range(1, nb_users+1):
        id_movies = data[:, 1][data[:, 0] == id_users] #contains the IDs of the movies rated by the id_user
        id_ratings = data[:, 2][data[:, 0] == id_users] #all movie ratings given by specific user
        ratings = np.zeros(nb_movies)
        ratings[id_movies-1] = id_ratings #these two lines are just so that the movies that are not rated by user have null (0) values
        new_data.append(list(ratings))
    return (new_data)
training_set = convert(training_set)
test_set = convert(test_set)
```

Below is a code that I tried which gave a number of errors, so many that I couldn't scroll up to the first one it threw.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
training_set = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u1.base', delimiter = '\t')
training_set = np.array(training_set, dtype='int')
test_set = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u1.test', delimiter = '\t')
test_set = np.array(test_set, dtype = 'int64')

nb_users = int(max(max(training_set[:, 0]), max(test_set[:, 0])))
nb_movies = int(max(max(training_set[:, 1]), max(test_set[:, 1])))

#The changes I made start here --

nb_timestamps = int(max(len(training_set[:, 3]), len(test_set[:, 3])))

ts_min = int(min(min(training_set[:, 3]), min(test_set[:, 3])))
ts_max = int(max(max(training_set[:, 3]), max(test_set[:, 3])))


def convert(data):
    new_data = [] #final list that we will return
    for timestamp in range(ts_min, ts_max+1):
        for id_users in range(1, nb_users+1):
            id_movies = data[:, 1][data[:, 0] == id_users][data[:, 3] == timestamp]
            #contains the IDs of the movies rated by the id_user
            id_ratings = data[:, 2][data[:, 0] == id_users][data[:, 3] == timestamp]
            ratings = np.zeros(nb_movies)
            ratings[id_movies-1] = id_ratings
        new_data.append(list(ratings))
    return (new_data)
training_set = convert(training_set)
test_set = convert(test_set)
```

Comment: Do you mind to give as an example of the output you would like to get? I'll eventually split the question. And I don't get why you are using loops with pandas.

Comment: @rpanai Imagine a 2D grid of ratings (row and columns as user and movies; so that each user is represented by a row and all the movies they rated are the columns), and atop that layer we're adding another layer of all the timestamps connected to each of those ratings hence making a 3D matrix. Why I'm using loops is because I'm still a beginner in data processing in general and unaware of many Pandas functions.

Comment: I added some code in an answer (which you shouldn't take as answer yet). It remains not clear to me how do you want to create the 3D matrix with timestamps.

Comment: And I'm removing not necessary tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>**Remark:** Please don't take this as an answer (yet).</s>

There are few things to improve in your code:

- When you read the csv you're taking the first row as header which means you are not considering all the data
- If in this case (asn it should be so) there is just one user can rate a movie only one time you can use `pd.pivot_table` in order to get your 2D matrix.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
training_set = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u1.base',
                           delimiter='\t',
                           header=None, # First row is not header
                           names=["user", "movie",
                                  "rating", "timestamp"]) # rename headers

# with pd.pivot_table you get a df where user are in rows 
# and movies in columns. The value is the rating for movie (i,j)
ratings = pd.pivot_table(training_set,
                         index=["user"],
                         columns=["movie"],
                         values="rating")
```

In case you want `0s` instead of `NaN` you can use `ratings.fillna(0)`. But I wouldn't do so. You should be care cos this will mess up the eventual statistics you want to extract.

In case you need the 2D matrix you can just use `ratings.values`.

**UPDATE**

In order to get your 3D matrix we can do the same pivoting with timestamps

```py
timestamps = pd.pivot_table(training_set,
                         index=["user"],
                         columns=["movie"],
                         values="timestamp")

# get matrix
mat_ratings = ratings.values
mat_timestamps = timestamps.values

# stack matrix
mat3d = np.dstack((mat_ratings, mat_timestamps))
```

You can now check that from 2 matrix with shape `(943, 1650)` we get one of shape `(943, 1650, 2)`. Note to get the shape of matrix `mat` just run `mat.shape`.

Comment: Now that we have the 2D matrix, I want the values of the timestamps associated with each (i, j) pair or (user, movie) pair attached to these values as the third dimension. For example, we have in u.base a row as "97 205 2 884238817" whose format is `USER_ID | MOVIE_ID | RATING | TIMESTAMP`. So now I want a kind of a "depth" added on to the cell (97, 205) with the value 884238817 as its timestamp (and it already has value 2 in the (97, 205, 0)th coordinate. This new timestamp gets stored in (97, 205, 1)th coordinate).

Comment: It looks to me that you basically want to do the same `pd.pivot_table` using `timestamp` as values and then kind of glue them

Comment: That's right. As long as the end result we get is what I'm trying to describe above it's fine. Could you edit your answer with the code to exactly 'glue' them?